# Is it important that line: "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' " should be on the bottom?

Tags: android, firebase

Is it important that line: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' should be on the bottom?

It is from firebase page with instruction how to add firebase to your android app
[image: It is from firebase page with instruction how to add firebase to your android app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for sure. It is stated at the `documentations` also. So it's the only place to put it and work successfully.

**Update** : Add dependencies for basic libraries required for the services you have enabled. This step requires that the apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' line be at the bottom of your app/build.gradle file so that no dependency collisions are introduced.

> **PS** : Taken from the [The Google Services Gradle Plugin.](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

Comment: why you think so? In my project for example other plugins add on the top

Answer (score 8):

It's no longer necessary to put it at the end of the build.gradle file. They removed the remark "*to the bottom of the file*" from the [newest docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file) and apply the plugin at the top now:

> In your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually app/build.gradle), apply the Google Services Gradle plugin:
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> // Add the following line:
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin
>
> android {
>   // ...
> }
> ```